# Relation for the current generated by a photo-diode in photo-conductive mode

Tags: infrared, photodiode, optoelectronics

If a photodiode with responsivity R is operated in photo-conductive mode with 
reverse bias voltage Vb and load resistance Rld what relation gives the output current from the photo-diode flowing trough Rld?

I know that generated current from the incoming optical power P is
Io = R*P, but I am not sure how is Io affected by Vb and Rl and when could reverse saturation current be neglected.

I am using this photo-diode [BPW 34 FS](https://www.osram.com/ecat/DIL%20SMT%20BPW%2034%20FS/com/en/class_pim_web_catalog_103489/global/prd_pim_device_2219539/) with incident power levels of about 10 - 1000 w/m^2.

Comment: Do you have a circuit diagram? Please draw one with the tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a first-order approximation, the reverse bias and loading resistor don't affect the photocurrent at all, so you have the correct formula:

$$I_p = P_o {\mathcal R}$$

In reality, these will have a small effect, but to account for it, you have to know the diode's effective shunt conductance. Then you can model the photodiode as a current source in parallel with the shunt conductance (and some capacitance if you want a dynamic model).

You may be able to estimate the shunt conductance from the photo-current and open-circuit voltage curves given in your device's datasheet. At 100 uW/cm<sup>2</sup> (1 W/m<sup>2</sup>), I'm estimating about 32 uS conductance, or 30 kohms resistance. The conductance increases as optical intensity increases.